# Optimizing a C# implementation of the Z-Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, search, time-complexity

I have tried to adapt a C++ Z-Algorithm implementation into C# and I arrived at the following:

```
    public static bool zAlgorithm(string pattern, string target)
    {
        string s = pattern + '$' + target;
        int n = s.Length;
        var z = new List<int>(new int[n]);

        int goal = pattern.Length;
        int r = 0, l = 0, i;
        for (int k = 1; k < n; k++)
        {
            if (k > r)
            {
                for (i = k; i < n && s[i] == s[i - k]; i++) ;
                if (i > k)
                {
                    z[k] = i - k;
                    l = k;
                    r = i - 1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                int kt = k - l, b = r - k + 1;
                if (z[kt] > b)
                {
                    for (i = r + 1; i < n && s[i] == s[i - k]; i++) ;
                    z[k] = i - k;
                    l = k;
                    r = i - 1;
                }
            }
            if ((z[k] == goal))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

FWIW it works, but I feel it could be faster. One notable difference is my usage of lists instead of vectors. Despite all my research indicating that this was the correct data structure to go for, I can't help but this a list is going to have a larger overhead. Perhaps I'm wrong, but nevertheless I'd primarily like to know what the most significant (if at all) optimisation I could implement is (and any others people would care to add). Thanks

Comment: Who is preventing you to use simple arrays? int[] numbers = new int[5];. Use it and test it.

Comment: @nosbor array manipulations are are O(n) vs O(1)?

Comment: What is the intended purpose of this line? `for (i = k; i < n && s[i] == s[i - k]; i++) ;`

Comment: @Sufo Not sure about C# but it should be O(1), and I suppose it is

Comment: @Brian I am not an expert but it increments i

Comment: Yeah, why do you use List instead of array - I don't see Add or Remove operations. You know that the List is internally backed with array, right?

Comment: @nosbor It didn't make sense at first; it looked like a typo where the `if (i > k)` block was supposed to be the loop body.

Comment: Definitely should use an array here, rather than `List<int>`. The primary benefit of `List<int>` is that it can grow dynamically. But your list is fixed length, so using `List<int>` just adds an additional (and needless) layer of bounds checking.

Comment: @Brian Maybe it do not make sense at first look but it definitely makes sense at all. It just calculates the "i". This is normal and you can find such empty loops in many algorithms.

Comment: @nosbor Just so.  I googled the algorithm and found a code sample that used a `while` loop instead.  That made sense (that incrementing i was the intention), with nothing else in the loop body.

Answer (score 0):

I originally rewrote some C# code I found on this post:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/z-algorithm-linear-time-pattern-searching-algorithm/

I posted it here as my initial answer.

I ended rewriting some very neat C code from:

http://e-maxx.ru/algo/z_function&xid=17259,15700023,15700124,15700149,15700168,15700173,15700186,15700189,15700190,15700195,15700201,15700205&usg=ALkJrhh4ycBYDU95Skmh2NICjKFdueiTrA

There is what seems to be a translation of the page above at:

http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/3107

I think that this code is optimal but I am still struggling to understand exactly how it works. I may post some updates as I tried to get my head around the Z algorithm.

```
public static int Search(string text, string pattern, bool once = false)
{
    var result = 0;
    var concat = pattern + "$" + text;
    var l = concat.Length;
    var n = pattern.Length;
    var za = new int[l];
    GetZarray(concat, za);

    for (var i = 0; i < l; ++i)
    {
        if (za[i] == n)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pattern found at index: {0}", i - n - 1);
            result ++;
            if (once) break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private static void GetZarray(string str, int[] za)
{
        var n = s.Length;
        var l = 0;
        var r = 0;
        for (var i = 1; i < n; ++i)
        {
            if (i <= r) z[i] = Math.Min(r - i + 1, z[i - l]);
            while (i + z[i] < n && s[z[i]] == s[i + z[i]]) ++z[i]; 
            if (i + z[i] - 1 <= r) continue;
            l = i;
            r = i + z[i] - 1;
        }
}
```

I will keep working on providing explanations for how this code works and add them to this answer in the future.